# How do I add a keybinding to a keymap that is on a prefix key

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, projectile

I just installed the pt.el package and now I want to bind projectile-pt to the default projectile search prefix (which is `C-c p s`). 
The goal is to have it as `C-c p s p` to begin with but also to have this follow the projectile prefix if I later change that to C-p for example (it would then automatically become C-p s p).

Is this possible? Sorry for the perhaps badly phrased question, will reword it if needed later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bindings for projectile are stored in `projectile-command-map`, so we can use `define-key` to add more stuff: `(define-key projectile-command-map (kbd "s p") #'projectile-pt)`.  This adds `s p` to whatever `projectile-keymap-prefix` happens to be.

Comment: Thanks! This made me understand how keymaps work a bit more! Merry Christmas! :)