# How to copy the symbol name at point?

Tags: copy-paste, symbols, thing-at-point

I want to copy the name of the symbol at point, without using the mouse.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-s C-c") '<copy_word>)
```

---

Possible word marking as `i-search` does on the following example usage (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/55321/18414)

For example: `[_id_hello_world]` and if cursor is in between `hello` and `world` I want to copy complete `_id_hello_world`.

Comment: Have you tried [multiple-cursors](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el)?

Comment: I haven't but I just want to copy a word under a single cursor

Comment: expand-region provides a really nice interface for quickly marking the word at point (and then the sentence, the paragraph, etc). Not exactly what you asked, but that's how I do these operations: https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el

Comment: Please clarify whether you mean copy (so it can be pasted/yanked) or select (highlighted as the region), or both.

Comment: Where does "copy", in the context of an editor and the original Q, mean select?

Comment: I meant copy but while copying it can also highlight the region but not mendatory. @Drew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is something like `(kill-new (thing-at-point 'symbol))`. When run, it first extracts the symbol at point and then adds it to the `kill-ring`, i.e. copies it. One caveat you have to keep in mind is that you need an interactive function/lambda in order to be able to invoke it with a keybinding. So actually you can have a binding of the form:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-s C-c")
   (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (kill-new (thing-at-point 'symbol))))
```

Comment: I am having following error: `error: Key sequence C-s C-c starts with non-prefix key C-s` but works with keybinding starting with `C-x` @Wojciech Gac

Comment: Right. I failed to notice that. `C-s` won't do as prefix, as it's already being used for search.

Answer (score 1):

While not strictly answering your question regarding one key copy symbol/word at point I like to use [expand-region](https://melpa.org/#/expand-region) since frequently I want to copy a lot at point without needing to move to the start, mark, move to end and copy. It might be of use.

For example, here are bindings to expand and contract the active region (and of course I then need to `M-w` to copy but it's still reasonably efficient:

```
 (use-package 
   expand-region 
   :config (defun er/select-call-f (arg) 
             (setq current-prefix-arg arg) 
             (call-interactively 'er/expand-region) 
             (exchange-point-and-mark)) 
   (defun selectFunctionCall() 
     (interactive) 
     (er/select-call-f 3)) 
   :bind ("<C-return>" . selectFunctionCall) 
   ("M-a" . er/expand-region) 
   ("M-s" . er/contract-region))
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `expand-region`. Be aware, that it's a bad advice to shadow keybindings `M-a` and `M-s`, they do useful things (i.e `M-a` in org-mode tables and `M-s o` is for occur). Read [more about keybindings at emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html)

Comment: fair comment re keys.