# How to jump to backward found word when switched into reverse incremental search?

Tags: isearch, words

When I do `I-search:` or `I-search-backward` , it starts right away from the first word it find.

Original behavior:

```
word1                                           |[cursor]word1 ; cursor moves here 
wor[cursor]d2 ;<= I press `ctrl+r` word [enter] |word2
word3                                           |word3
```

---

For example, when I am in `I-search`, I want to start doing backward search and press `ctrl+r` but in the first press it remains in the current found word (cursor move into its beginning) and on the second press to `ctrl+r`, `emacs jumps to the found word on backward.

**Example:**

```
word1                                           |word1
wor[cursor]d2 ;<= I press `ctrl+s` word [enter] |word2
word3                                           |word3[cursor]; cursor moves here
```

then

```
word1                                           |word1
word2                                           |word2
word3[cursor] ;<= I press `ctrl+r` word [enter] |[cursor]word3 ; cursor moves here
```

at this stage I want cursor to move beginning of `word2` like it should do on its original behavior.

---

=> I was wondering when the switch from `I-search:` to `I-search-backward` or visa versa, can the action take place on the first click instead of two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all based on where the cursor is when you start the search.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Basic Isearch` says:

> A backward search finds matches that **end before** the starting point,
> just as a forward search finds matches that **begin after** it.

Hence for:

```
word1
wor[cursor]d2
word3
```

Searching backwards for `word` cannot find word2 because that instance of "word" doesn't end before [cursor].

```
word1
word2
word3[cursor]
```

Searching backwards here, we will initially find word3, as that instance of "word" ends before [cursor].

---

Edit: The following is *extremely* minimally tested, but give this a whirl:

```el
(define-advice isearch-repeat (:before (direction &optional count) goto-other-end)
  "If reversing, start the search from the other end of the current match."
  (unless (eq isearch-forward (eq direction 'forward))
    (when isearch-other-end
      (goto-char isearch-other-end))))
```

Comment: Wow your code works perfect, I don't know how it makes the magic but thank you

Comment: I found a small bug, not sure could it be related to this. On following example (https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/2a26b7c64386167f86e443656d62c614) when I do `C-s` on top of first `_PATH` work it does not see the second `_PATH`. But when I add space after the second `_PATH` word it sees that

Comment: I can't replicate that.  I assume you're searching for `_PATH`.  Please test starting from `emacs -Q`

Comment: I haven't understood the problem, in that case.  Please give a recipe to reproduce this starting from `emacs -Q`.  Ask a new question if you can't do it in a comment (but if you do that, please firstly verify whether the code in this Answer actually makes a difference, as there's no purpose in referencing this if it's not relevant).

Comment: sorry the problem I was having is related to `(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-w")   'isearch-forward-symbol-at-point)` which was related to this answer (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55306/how-do-i-add-a-keybinding-to-use-during-an-interactive-isearch-c-s/55321#55321) . I think instead of capturing `_PATH` it captures `_PATH=` which fails the search

Comment: Seems like `isearch-repeat` does not work in emacsclient 27.2 :( // I am having following error: `Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (direction) "If reversing, start the search from the other end of the current match." (if (eq isearch-forward (eq direction 'forward)) nil (if isearch-other-end (progn (goto-char isearch-other-end))))), 2
`

Comment: Emacs 27.1 added an optional argument, so I've updated the advice to match.